# Is it possible to have a main Ansible play with smaller "sub-plays"?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to achieve something that should be trivial, but after a lot of searching I simply can't find anything that comes close to what I want.

Basically, I have a large group of servers, with serveral subgroups, similar to this one (the actual group and its subgroups are much larger than this, but you get what I mean):

```
my_large_infrastructure:
  children:
    frontend_servers:
      children:
        frontend_servers_cluster1:
          hosts:
            server1:
              ansible_host: 10.0.0.1
            server2:
              ansible_host: 10.0.0.2
        frontend_server_cluster2:
          hosts:
            server3:
              ansible_host: 10.0.0.3
            server4:
              ansible_host: 10.0.0.4
          [...]
          [...]
          [...]
```

Now, let's say I have a big play that configures the firewall:

```
---
- name: Apply firewall rules to My Large infrastructure
  hosts: my_large_infrastructure
  become: true
  tasks:

  - name: Apply firewall rules on the Frontend Cluster1 Servers
    include_role:
      name: firewall_management
    vars:
      config_file: 'ipv4_firewall_cluster1.j2'
      ipv6_config_file: 'ipv6_firewall_cluster1.j2'

  - name: Apply firewall rules on the Frontend Cluster2 Servers
    include_role:
      name: firewall_management
    vars:
      config_file: 'ipv4_firewall_cluster2.j2'
      ipv6_config_file: 'ipv6_firewall_cluster2.j2'
```

This play targets all hosts in "my_large_infrastructure", however, I need to have those separate tasks that should target the smaller subgroups, in order to configure the firewall for "frontend_servers_cluster1", "frontend_servers_cluster2", etc.

So, obviously, the easy solution would be to just have different plays for each subgroup and be done with it, but I would prefer to have a more elegant solution, where I have one big play with the "Apply firewall rules to My Large infrastructure" name, and tasks (or "sub-plays", if possible) that target the subgroups, like this:

```
PLAY [Apply firewall rules to My Large infrastructure]
*****************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts]
*****************************************************************************************
ok: [server1]
ok: [server2]
ok: [server3]
ok: [server4]


TASK [Apply firewall rules on the Frontend Cluster1 Servers]
*****************************************************************************************
ok: [server1]
ok: [server2]

TASK [Apply firewall rules on the Frontend Cluster2 Servers]
*****************************************************************************************
ok: [server3]
ok: [server4]
```

Now, I could achieve something like this with a "when: my_group in group_names" condition, but then I will have dozens upon dozens of skipped servers in each task (something that I don't really like). So I feel like there has to be a better solution where I end up with a line like this:

```
PLAY [Apply firewall rules to My Large infrastructure]
```

and after that smaller tasks (or anything else) that would look like these (without any skipped servers in the firewall configuration):

```
TASK [Apply firewall rules on the Frontend Cluster1 Servers]
```

PS: sorry for the very large question/description.

Comment: "_obviously, the easy solution would be to just have different plays for each subgroup and be done with it_", right, that's probably correct. "_but I would prefer to have a more elegant solution, where I have one big play ... and tasks (or "sub-plays", if possible) that target the subgroups_" event if I don't understand what do mean with that I've provided a small minimal example as answer.

Comment: My initial goal was to have one big play with some nested tasks / some type of sub-play (for more readability), but, yeah, your solution works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html), for an example inventory of

```yaml
infrastructure:
  children:
    frontend:
      children:
        cluster1:
          hosts:
            server1.example.com:
            server2.example.com:
        cluster2:
          hosts:
            server3.example.com:
            server4.example.com:
```

**`infra.yml`**

```bash
ansible-inventory -i infra.yml --graph
@all:
  |--@infrastructure:
  |  |--@frontend:
  |  |  |--@cluster1:
  |  |  |  |--server1.example.com
  |  |  |  |--server2.example.com
  |  |  |--@cluster2:
  |  |  |  |--server3.example.com
  |  |  |  |--server4.example.com
  |--@ungrouped:
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: infrastructure
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

- hosts: cluster1
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

- hosts: cluster2
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

called via `sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --inventory infra.yml --user ${ANSIBLE_USER} --ask-pass plays.yml` will result into an execution of

```yaml
PLAY [infrastructure] ******

TASK [debug] ***************
ok: [server1.example.com] =>
  msg: server1.example.com
ok: [server2.example.com] =>
  msg: server2.example.com
ok: [server3.example.com] =>
  msg: server3.example.com
ok: [server4.example.com] =>
  msg: server4.example.com

PLAY [cluster1] ************

TASK [debug] ***************
ok: [server1.example.com] =>
  msg: server1.example.com
ok: [server2.example.com] =>
  msg: server2.example.com

PLAY [cluster2] ************

TASK [debug] ***************
ok: [server3.example.com] =>
  msg: server3.example.com
ok: [server4.example.com] =>
  msg: server4.example.com
```

**Further Documentation and Similar Q&A**

- [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html)
- [Ansible: How to get hostname without domain name?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/17139/6017)
- [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html)

Comment: Nice! This is actually a pretty simple and clever way of doing it and it does achieve what I wanted. Thank you!